# Is it possible to get your loot from the Public Test Realm?

Tags: diablo-iii

Blizzard allows [Characters copy](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13242104384?page=1#3) from one of your account (EU, US etc.) to the PTR in order to test the latest patch but is it possible the other way arround. My biggest concern is : if I loot an incredibly good item (or something I've been looking for month on the "real" server) in the PTR, will I be able to transfer it back on my main account ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.

Blizzard state [in their forums](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13242534258):

> **As a reminder:** Any progress made on the PTR will not transfer over to your live account.

Comment: Right, I can't believe I missed that line at the end of the post, thanks ! (i can't upvote your answer yet)

Answer (score 7):

**No**.

It is impossible for a couple reasons:

- Balance: the drop rates might be different on PTR than on your normal account.
- compatibility: the items that drop on the PTR might not even exist on the "normal" system, it might have a new affix. Or it might have an affix that can't happen in the old version yet.

Answer (score 3):

No.The test realms are for testing,items can change etc. :)

> **None of the progress made on the PTR will transfer back to the live game**, so any items, experience, or achievements you earn while on the PTR will *not* advance your characters on the live servers. It's a great place to test out the new changes and features from the patch, though. I definitely recommend hopping over there to try it out if you're interested in any of the new stuff.

Check out [this Bluepost](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13243924472#12).

Comment: Note that there is an error in that quote.  It should say, "...PTR will not advance..." -- the "not" is missing in the original.